# Do Adjoint Functors preserve mono-sources?

Tags: category-theory

A functor $F: \mathfrak{C} \to \mathfrak{D}$ is called *adjoint* if for any $D \in \mathfrak{D}$ there exist an object $C \in \mathfrak{C}$ and a morphism $f: D \to F(C)$ such that whenever we consider $C' \in \mathfrak{C}$ and $f: D \to F(C')$ we can find a unique morphism $\hat f: C \to C'$ in $\mathfrak{C}$ such that $f'=F(\hat f) \circ f$.

Now, I want to show that $F$ preserves mono-sources, namely if $\mathcal{S}=(m_i: A \to A_i)_{i \in I}$ is a mono-source ($\mathcal{S} \circ r=\mathcal{S} \circ s \implies r=s$), then $F(\mathcal{S})=(F(m_i): F(A) \to F(A_i))_{i \in I}$ is a mono-source.

Here there is my attempt of proof:

I consider a mono-source $\mathcal{S}=(m_i: A \to A_i)_{i \in I}$ in $\mathfrak{C}$. Let $r,s: B \to F(A)$ be such that $F(\mathcal{S}) \circ r=F(\mathcal{S}) \circ s$. As $F$ is adjoint, there exist an object $C \in \mathfrak{C}$ and a morphism $f: B \to F(C)$ as in the definition. By our choice of $r$ and $s$, there exist $\hat r,\hat s: C \to A$ such tht $r=F(\hat r) \circ f$ and $s=F(\hat s) \circ f$.

At this point, we get the equalities

$$
F(\mathcal{S}) \circ r=F(\mathcal{S}) \circ F(\hat r) f=F(\mathcal{S} \circ \hat r) \circ f
$$
and
$$
F(\mathcal{S}) \circ r=F(\mathcal{S}) \circ F(\hat s) f=F(\mathcal{S} \circ \hat s) \circ f,
$$
whence the equality $F(\mathcal{S} \circ \hat r) \circ f=F(\mathcal{S} \circ \hat s) \circ f$. I would like to conclude that

$$
\mathcal{S} \circ \hat r=\mathcal{S} \circ \hat s
$$
but I have no clue.

In this way, using the assumption that $\mathcal{S}$ is a mono-source in $\mathfrak{C}$, then I would get $\hat r=\hat s$ and hence $r=F(\hat r) \circ f=F(\hat s) \circ f$.

Comment: This definition of "adjoint" is... strange.

Comment: It has been given by Adamek... see The Joy of Cats, pag. 305. The proof I described is given some pages later

Comment: No, I can see what motivates it; it's just very uncommon and probably a bit confusing ("Joy" is a wonderful book, but has plenty of these little quirks...).

Comment: There is only a step of the proof which is unclear for me. Why does the equality $F(\mathcal{S} \circ \hat r) \circ f=F(\mathcal{S} \circ \hat s) \circ f$ imply that $\mathcal{S} \circ \hat r=\mathcal{S} \circ \hat s$?

Comment: $F$ is "adjoint" if and only if given any object $D\in \mathfrak D$, the comma category $(D/F)$ has an initial object. It is way simpler to reason in this way (I did the math, but using different notation than yours, sorry)

Comment: I do not understand how this hint may be useful for my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in my comment, an easy translation of the property of being an "adjoint" for a functor $F$ is that for every object D of its codomain, the comma category $(D/F)$ has an initial object.

Note that this condition can be very useful: each functor with that property is [final](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+functor), which is good to know sometimes.

The two notions (finality and being an adjoint) are related, but I can't think of a sharp theorem right now (I reserve myself the right to come back at this later). For the moment observe that every right adjoint functor is final. I'd try to ask myself if an "adjoint" functor is a weak form of being a right adjoint, or something like that.

So far, this is just context. Coming to your question instead, you're in the following situation: let's consider a "mono-source" $\cal S$ (modern terminology: a "jointly monic" family ${\cal S} = \{s : A_s\to B_s\}$ of arrows). You want to show that the family $F{\cal S} = \{Fs : FA_s\to FB_s\}$ is also jointly monic.

To this end, consider two arrows $r,t : E\to FA_s$ such that $Fs\circ r = Fs\circ t$; since $F$ is adjoint, there exist unique arrows $r',t'$ such that $r=Fr'\circ z, t=Ft'\circ z$ for the initial object $z : E\to FU$ in the comma category $(E/F)$. So you're left with the equality
$$
F(s\circ r')\circ z = F(s\circ t')\circ z
$$ valid for every $s\in\cal S$. Now, this common composition is a certain map $E\to FB_s$, which must be $Fu\circ z$ for a unique map $u$. So, $s\circ r'=s\circ t'$. This concludes.

Comment: Actually, what's relevant here is the comma categories are (absolutely) cofiltered, meaning that every (even non-finite) diagram in each comma category has a cone over it. This is equivalent to the functor $F$ being flat, i.e. every cone over the $F$-image of a diagram factors through the $F$-image of a cone over the diagram. The same argument then works using the cone with vertex $z\colon E\to FU$ over the diagram consisting of $r,t\colon E\to FA_s\Rightarrow FB_s$.  Thus flat functors preserve mono-sources. Moreover, they also preserve weak limits, and so also limits, if they exist.

Comment: The connection with adjoints is Borceux's "More General Adjoint Functor Theorem" (see Handbook Volume I) which states a functor from a Cauchy-complete locally small category is a right adjoint if and only if it is flat for small diagrams and satisfies the solution set condition (here small can be replaced with any regular cardinal/arity class).